# Drivers for USB/MIDI device

Tags: driver, midi

I am new to Raspbian. I managed to get Pure Data to run, but now I am trying to get this MIDI device running: http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/uno

Does anyone have any advice for how to install the drivers? Or if it is even possible?

Comment: Did it!(in terminal)
sudo apt-get install midisport-firmware

Comment: Must have been a very old version of the device …

Comment: You should either delete or better yet answer your own question.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Please feel free to post your solution as an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

To give this question an answer, the asker has given its solution in a comment:

> Did it!(in terminal) sudo apt-get install midisport-firmware